# Space in CSV file detected as comma

Tags: c#, string, csv, separator

I try to generate CSV file, which contains 4 columns.
One of this columns is Name which contains First and Last name separated with space.

When I write this text data to `.csv` file, it detect space as comma and add additional column. Example :

`Name - First LastName` converts into :

```
 Name | AdditionalColumn

First | LastName
```

but should be just

```
          Name |
First LastName |
```

To generate file I use next method :

```
public string Export(bool includeHeaderLine = true)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Get properties using reflection.
        IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        if (includeHeaderLine)
        {
            //add header line.
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                sb.Append(propertyInfo.Name).Append(",");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
        }

        //add value for each property.
        foreach (T obj in _objects)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null))).Append(",");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Values which contain a separator must be quoted.

Comment: The PropertyInfo class as a enumeration that is returning the names of the column and is causing the issue.  It can't be fixed with the code posted.

Comment: What do you mean "detect"? Your code *doesn't* read the CSV file it just writes text to a file. Any unexpected results are caused by the code or the data. Eg, are you sure your property values don't contain commas or newlines?

Comment: There is a good library for handling CSV Files. Look in nuget packages for CsvHelper. https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, under "detect" I mean that when I open csv file I see my Name is 2 columns, cause it contains space (as I understand)

Comment: @demo you haven't posted any examples of the text. Besides, what do you mean the name is 2 columns? How did you open the file? Are you sure it isn't simply spilling out of the spreadsheet cell? Have you tried resizing the column?

Comment: Open it how? In Excel? Using excel to just open a CSV is not the best way to determine if your file is not formatted to your expectations. Open it in Notepad and review the output. The file may have no issues when trying to perform a read in code as a CSV. If your purpose is to create a file that can be opened in Excel then please note that in your question.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz, recomended library also split Name like "Tom Hardy" in 2 columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I mean that : I have name like "Tom Hardy". So in csv file I get "Tom" and "Hardy" in different columns

Comment: @demo did `sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();` work as it doesn't for me but let `sb.Length--;` does.. odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, how do check created CSV?
If you open it Excell, than first try to modify MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value) and quote value with spaces:

```
...    
if (output.Contains(",") || output.Contains("\"") || output.Contains(" "))
                output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
...
```

If you export CSV with header, also, check generated CSV in notepad, do you have double comma after "Name".